# Rails sql query, filtering thousands of records and summing up one column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sum

I have a database table with thousands of rows. I would like to run a report that basically lists all clients who have spent more than £2,000 with us.

The table has a lot of columns, but the ones I am interested are as follows:

```
======================================================
|  ClientKey | PVID | ShortText           | Payments |
======================================================
|  13276     | 76668| Paid by PET HEALTH  | 56.79    |
|  12893     | 62368| Paid by PET HEALTH  | 42.79    |
|  23782     | 87468| Paid by PET HEALTH  | 26.29    |
|  23246     | 79868| Paid by PET HEALTH  |-16.52    |
======================================================
```

I need to group the rows by ClientKey and sum up the Payments columns. Then I need to filter them by removing anything where the Payments column sum is less than £2,000. I also need to ignore any rows where the PVID is 44444.

So far I know I will need to have something similar to the following:

```
@clinical = Clinical.where("ShortText LIKE 'Paid by PET HEALTH' AND PVID != 44444")
```

That takes care of filtering the rows down to exclude anything with a PVID of 44444 and only showing rows where the ShortText contains Paid by PET HEALTH.

I can't get my head around how to sum up the payments column for each of the ClientKey's.

The end result I would like is the ability to do this:

```
Client Key 13276 has spent £99,999 so far.
Client Key 21342 has spent £3,200 so far.
Client Key 32312 has spent £2,110 so far.
```

Any help and/or pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
Clinical.select("ClientKey as client_key, sum(Payments) as total_payments").group("ClientKey").where("ShortText LIKE 'Paid by PET HEALTH' AND PVID != 44444")
```

For more information about the grouping, refer [rails guide - ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

Comment: 'ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'ClinicalText' in 'having clause': SELECT ClientKey as client_key, sum(Payments) as total_payments FROM `clinical`  GROUP BY ClientKey HAVING ClinicalText LIKE 'Paid by PET HEALTH' AND PVID != 44444 ORDER BY FullDateTime DESC, total_payments DESC):'

Comment: That's the error I get, it seems to be looking for a table called 'having clause' rather than clinical. Is .having the correct way to do it?

Comment: You are right @dannymcc. Having clause is mostly used for aggregate functions. But, it can be used in place of where as well, though it is less-performant. I think the error you got was because you misspelled the name of the column. Anyway, I have modified my answer accordingly.